# C# Dotras check if dialer is already connected

Tags: c#

I have made a dialer program which dials a pppoe connection name 'pppoe2'.
How can I add a check if the 'pppoe2' is already connected or not? like if connected, show message , else dial it?

Comment: ok got it.
`
if (conn != null)
                    MessageBox.Show("Dialer - Already connected!");
                else
                    handle = rasDialer1.DialAsync();
`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (conn != null) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Dialer - Already connected!");
} 
else 
{ 
    handle = rasDialer1.DialAsync(); 
}
```